# How can you update data in real time in database and render it?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

I'm trying to create a twitter clone and right now I'm creating the part where people are allowed to send tweets through a form, when that form is clicked, an axios post request is enabled and the tweet is added to that request. But like this it doesn't allow me to update in real time as i'm using a `useEffect` hook to get the tweets, but that's only updated once when the page loads as doing it more times would cause the page to be slower. How can I make so that it updates the tweets in real time and render them in real time?

```
import React, {useContext, useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import './tweetpage.css'
import Navbar from './navbar.js'
import InsertPhotoIcon from '@material-ui/icons/InsertPhoto';
import GifIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Gif';
import EqualizerIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Equalizer';
import EmojiEmotionsIcon from '@material-ui/icons/EmojiEmotions';
import CalendarTodayIcon from '@material-ui/icons/CalendarToday';
import SearchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Search';
import TextareaAutosize from 'react-textarea-autosize';
import {dataStatesContext} from './Contexts/dataStatesContext.js'
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { InputAdornment } from '@material-ui/core';
import Input from '@material-ui/core/Input';
import axios from 'axios'



function Tweetpage() {
  const {tweet, setTweet} = useContext(dataStatesContext)
  const {data, setData} = useContext(dataStatesContext)
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
      axios.get('http://localhost:4000/tweets')
      .then(res => setPosts(res.data))
  }, [])

  const submitForm = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault()

      const tweets = {
        tweets: tweet
      }
      axios.post('http://localhost:4000/tweets/add', tweets)
      .then(res => console.log())

    }


  console.log(posts)
    return (
        <div className="tweetpage_____div">
          <Navbar />
          <div className="tweetpage____tweetit">
              <div className="tweetpage__border">
                <h1 className="tweetpage_____home">Home</h1>
                <form onSubmit={submitForm}>
                <TextareaAutosize onChange={(e) => setTweet(e.target.value)} className="tweetpage_____input" placeholder="What's happening?" maxLength="280"/>
                <div className="tweetpage_____icons">
                  <InsertPhotoIcon />
                  <GifIcon />
                  <EqualizerIcon />
                  <EmojiEmotionsIcon />
                  <CalendarTodayIcon />
                    <button className="button_____tweet">Tweet</button>
                </div>
                </form>
                {posts.map((post, i) => {
                  return <div key={i}>{post.tweets}</div>
                })}
              </div>
          </div>
          <div className="tweetpage_____search">
            <Input
            disableUnderline={true}
            placeholder="Search on Twitter"
       className="tweet__searchitem"
       startAdornment={
         <InputAdornment position="start">
           <SearchIcon />
         </InputAdornment>
       } />
          </div>

        </div>
    )
}

export default Tweetpage
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code inside then block

```
.then((res) => setPosts([...posts,tweet]););
```

Comment: ```TypeError: posts.map is not a function``` getting this error

Comment: I've updated the code. Can you try again?

Answer (score 0):

To implement real time you need to look at web sockets, one common library used is socket.io both on client and server and through that you create channels in backend and then in front you listen those channels, all that happens in real time.